# Unable able to float HTML tables left and right

Tags: html

After trying all suggestions and tags I am unable to float my tables side by side.  Can someone assist me or recommend a solution?

**Electrode Location Left**  

    


                                    
                                                 **Date**    
                                                 **Contact**   
                                                 **Case**   
                                                 **Voltage**   
                                                 **Pulse Width**   
                                                 **Frequency**   
                                    
                                       
                                                 {{ _________________}}    
                                                 {{ _________________}}    
                                                 {{ _________________}}    
                                                 {{ _________________}}    
                                                 {{ _________________}}    
                                                 {{ _________________}}    

                                    






                                
                                

                  
    

          **Electrode Location Right**  
    
                                       
                                                 **Date**    
                                                 **Contact**   
                                                 **Case**   
                                                 **Voltage**   
                                                 **Pulse Width**   
                                                 **Frequency**   
                                    
                                       
                                       
                                                 {{ _________________}}    
                                                 {{ _________________}}    
                                                 {{ _________________}}    
                                                 {{ _________________}}    
                                                 {{ _________________}}    
                                                 {{ _________________}}

Comment: You need show us the html extract you are using

Comment: show some of your code or create a fiddle to showcase your issue.

Comment: please add a [mcve] for faster troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

You could use a stylsheet to do this

**table.html**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="floatLeft">
<tr><table>
<tr><td class="box3_t">TEXT HERE
<tr><td class="box3_b"></td></tr>
</td></tr></table>
</div>

<div class="floatRight">
<tr><table>
<tr><td class="box4_t">TEXT HERE
<tr><td class="box4_b"></td></tr>
</td></tr></table>
</div>
</div>
```

**table.css**

```
.floatLeft { width: 50%; float: left; }
.floatRight {width: 50%; float: right; }
.container { overflow: hidden; }
```